# Random Walk: Right p-value method?

Tags: p-value, graph-theory, random-walk

Based on a stochastic matrix/graph $G$, I want to conduct a series of random walks to get an idea which are frequent interaction partners for a starting node (not only connected by the first edge). I start with a single node $v_{init}$, perform a number of steps and then restart the random walk and start again at $v_{init}$. The result of this is a frequency table for all nodess $V$ in $G$, where every $v_i$ is initialized with 0 counts and incremented each time the node was visited. From this my hypthesis are:

$H_0$: The observed frequencies for a node $v_i$ in $V$ are expected

$H_1$: The observed frequenies for a node $v_i$ are higher than expected

This is now more a theoretical problem since the frequencies that I looked at looked almost equal to the number of times a node was visited when $v_{init}$ was drawn randomly. However, I am still wondering if there is an naaive solution to compute p-values here.

Comment: What hypothesis test do you have so that you are looking for $p$-values? You have not specified it.